# WPF DataGrid Require Text Column Overflow

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, overlap

How do you let text in one column overflow (overlap) the next column(s) like Excel.

[From Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azNlO.png)

The DataGrid gives this result.
[From DataGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4OhR.png)

I'm at a loss of what property to set or how to style this.

Just using very basic xaml at this point.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" ></DataGrid>
```

Comment: Excel does it different way, depending whether next cell has values. You can try to play with `Popup`.

Comment: WPF is not excel. There is no such behaviour supported in wpf.  You can make text wrap to next line in a textblock but not jump out one textblock to another.

Comment: You can also make datagrid column widths auto so they may expand to the widest piece of text in them.

Comment: Or. You could put your full text in a tooltip as well as the textblock. Even if truncated in the textblock you can mouse over and see the full text in the tooltip, since this is in a layer above the rest of the controls and not constrained to the textblock container.